# Parsing JSON into Excel but having an Error

Tags: json, excel, vba

I have been using below code to convert the data from JSON to Excel but below JSON format is not converting into excel and having an error `Run time error: Invalid procedure call or argument` on the line `ws.Cells(r, "C").Value = JSON("sku")`

Here is my code that i have been using. I do not know why the error is appearing when it works for other JSON format instead of this one.

Your help will be appreciated.

```
    Dim objRequest  As Object
    Dim strUrl      As String
    Dim blnAsync    As Boolean
    Dim strResponse As String
    Dim idno        As Long
    Dim ws          As Worksheet
    Dim JSON        As Object
    Dim lrow As Long
    
    Set ws = Sheet4
    
    lrow = ws.Range("C" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    
    Set objRequest = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    strUrl = "url"
    blnAsync = True
    
    With objRequest
        .Open "GET", strUrl, blnAsync
        .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
        .send
        
        While objRequest.readyState <> 4
            DoEvents
        Wend
        
        strResponse = .ResponseText
    End With
    
    Set JSON = ParseJson(strResponse)
    
'    Debug.Print strResponse
            r = 2
            ws.Cells(r, "C").Value = JSON("sku")
            'r = r + 1
```

Comment: There's a missing `]` at the end of the JSON data, is that a typo?

Comment: No its not a typo i forgot to mentioned because this json is for some rows so it would have ] at the end. Edited.

Comment: Please indicate which line the runtime error occurs on.

Comment: Updated the line where the error was persisting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if there is a option for this in JSONConverter but as far as I know, it doesn't like to parse JSON string that starts with a collection so I would usually create a key manually so that it will convert properly.

Below example also shows how you can loop through the collection and get the value for `sku`:

```
'.... Continue after you post the API...
    
    Dim strResponse As String
    strResponse = .responseText
    
    Dim resultDict As Object
    Set resultDict = ParseJson("{""result"":" & strResponse & "}")
    
    Dim i As Long
    Dim resultNum As Long
    resultNum = resultDict("result").Count
    
    For i = 1 To resultNum
        Debug.Print resultDict("result")(i)("id")
        Debug.Print resultDict("result")(i)("sku")
        Debug.Print resultDict("result")(i)("upc")
        

        'Loop through skuList collection
        Dim j As Long
        For j = 1 To resultDict("result")(i)("skuList").Count
            Debug.Print vbTab & resultDict("result")(i)("skuList")(j)("id")
            Debug.Print vbTab & resultDict("result")(i)("skuList")(j)("sku")
            Debug.Print vbTab & resultDict("result")(i)("skuList")(j)("skuTitle")
        Next j
    Next i
```

Comment: @Arham - I made a typo in my original code (`testdict` should be `resultDict`) so please test using the edited code.

Comment: Getting an error `Object Required` on the line `Set resultDict = JsonConverter.ParseJson("{""result"":" & strResponse & "}")` and i have updated the whole code above @Raymond Wu

Comment: @Arham perhaps change to `Set resultDict = ParseJson("{""result"":" & strResponse & "}")`

Comment: Its working yeahhh great. Thank you and if i would like to get the result for others then what should i do i means `upc` `epid` how the data will come. I have to develop simialr codes for each column separate.

Comment: @Arham Like I shown you in the example, you get `sku` using `resultDict("result")(i)("sku")` so to get `upc`, you will use `resultDict("result")(i)("upc")`. It's like a tree structure, you can paste the JSON string into http://json.parser.online.fr/ and it will format nicely for you to visualise.

Comment: Thank you very much @Raymond Wu just need to make sure that all data will come accordingly i mean sames rows data will come or it will be shuffled by using the codes.

Comment: @Arham I have expanded my answer to show you more examples, within the loop the data will come from the same row. in your JSON string `skuList` has a collection in itself too so there will be another `For` loop to access the key-value in each item.

Comment: Thank again i got it.