# Get json data in vba

Tags: json, excel, vba

I am new to VBA and I am trying to use an API. So far everything works, but I just dont know how to get the data from the json file. Thanks for the help in advance.

Here is how the json looks like:

[image]

[image]

I tried to get the names of all the companies so this was my approach(which unfortunately doesn't work):

```
    ' Parse the JSON
Dim response As Object
Set response = JsonConverter.ParseJson(request.ResponseText)

' Access the data

Dim comp As Variant
For Each comp In response

    Debug.Print comp("name")
    
Next comp
```

Comment: Is it an initial parent dictionary and therefore not a loop but just `response("name")` ?  Otherwise, can you provide the code necessary to return this json? Or share the json as actual json and not as an image?

Comment: I think u are right with the 'initial parent dictionary', but with response("name") only one name is printed? But I want to print all names? btw Thanks for the answer :)

Comment: What does *not work* means? Just saying that isn't helpful. Did you get an error message? Or it did not do what you were expecting? Please elaborate.

Comment: This answer might help, since your JSON looks like it starts with a collection. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68660511/parsing-json-into-excel-but-having-an-error/68660582#68660582

Comment: We need to see the actual json (use [edit] to insert, rather than an image). It looks to me, from the image above, that you have a JSON object (VBA dictionary) returned with 23 keys.